# Directory '/Users/vsts/agent/2.152.1/work/16/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin, azure-devops, pipeline

I'm getting below warning while building Artifacts on Azure Deops pipeline.
    Unable to integrate continuous deployment because publish Artifact for Xamarin iOS project:

```
[warning]Directory '/Users/vsts/agent/2.152.1/work/16/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'
```

I'm building this solution for **Xamarin.iOS and need to publish it on App Center**.

YAML for PublishBuildartifacts

```
task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
inputs:
PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

YAML for CopyFiles
steps:

```
task: CopyFiles@2
displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
inputs:

SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
Contents: '**/*.ipa'
TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
CleanTargetFolder: true
condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Comment: Does the same warning still occurred after remove the single quotes? Feel free to let me know the last status:-)

Comment: Yes. It still occurred

Comment: Thanks @MerlinLiang-MSFT
While checking in the iOS project, I selected appropriate provisioning profile for AdHoc. And checked in the solution again and it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

The error caused by your **Contents** format of CopyFiles task is incorrect. As a folder path, you should not use `/`, modify it to `\`.

So change your the `Contents` as:

```
Contents: **\*.ipa
```

Comment: Tried this solution but not working. It gives same warning for building Artifacts

Comment: @SnehalJadhav Do you also with the single quotes? Remove it when you specified the file path(just remove the single quote of file path of Contents). It may succeed.